# Composite volumetric video across multiple azure kinect sensors

Tags: azurekinect

My question is can the recorded data from daisy-chained azure kinect sensors be combined into a single volumetric video. I have not seen any documentation regarding this.

Comment: Hi have you looked in to this example? https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Samples/tree/master/opencv-kinfu-samples

Comment: I have not seen this. Thank you for bringing it to my attention.